# 5v / USB standalone surge protection? Buck/boost boards?

Tags: usb, surge-protection

Not an engineer, but relatively handy. This is just out of my depth on what is possible (and hopefully, commercially available)

I had a 1/4 second brownout/blackout that fried all my wyzecam v2 (I tested with fresh wall wart PSUs to make sure they weren't the problem, no luck). I took a look at the circuit board and it looks like everything is surface mount, too small for me to just replace/test w spare capacitors (my default first step to try to fix anything electronic), so I'll have to buy a bunch of new cams (thank goodness they are cheap).

More than half my cams are in enclosures that have very little room for more than the camera - definitely not enough for a large surge protector or power strip. I looked on my favorite overseas parts website, but search terms like "standalone USB surge protector" just result in pages and pages of plug-in strips and other stuff that isn't relevant to my needs. I'd welcome suggestions on better search terms, but given that I didn't find a commercially made in-line 5v-5v USB surge protector, I was wondering if a buck or boost converter (maintaining the same voltage in and out) would offer any surge protection. And- if it matters what *type* of converter, then what components or keywords should I be looking for before buying?

2 of the cams have battery backup using an single-cell 18650/UPS board, but that wasn't marketed as having and surge protection properties, so I'd put surge protection in front of them as well.

I appreciate any suggestions and insights from the community on my options for small 5v-5v surge protection. I know nothing will be perfect or protect against everything, but something has to be better than nothing... I don't expect to be safe from lightning, but hopefully I can mitigate surges associated with momentary brownouts/blackouts?

Many thanks for your expertise!

Comment: something like this (https://www.techinn.com/en/canyon-ac-1x-usb-charger-with-surge-protection-and-micro-usb-connector-with-smart-ic/137562832/p) ?

Answer (score 1):

so there are surge protecting devices for 5V and USB - just a quick pick from a supplier I know: https://www.bourns.com/docs/product-datasheets/cd143a-sr05lc.pdf?sfvrsn=3be0efe9_6

But this is the very last resort and the smaller the devices are, the less energy over time they can absorb.

Don't know which country you are from, but here in Germany there are so called Type 1,2 and three surge protectors. Type one can absorb the most energy, Type 3 is the fastest of the three. To protect the devices in your house, flat,... from external surge energy you need all three! Type 1&2 can be combined in one housing and are placed in the cabinet where your fuses are. Type 3 is normaly in special multi socket Power plugs or in devices like a USV. Also there are additional surge protectors for antennas (e.g. sattelite TV) and copper cable e.g. telephone lines.

I would opt for the equivalent of our Type 1,2,3 surge protectors - even if they are somewhat expensive!. A PCB scale surge protection device normaly is to weak for external surges you need to expect from brownout/blackout/lightnings.

PS: these surge protectors are like airbags - once triggered, you need to replace em
Also if you prepare yourself with Type 1,2,3 surge protectors, and your neighbours don't... well current follows the easy path. Its then more likely they get gilled, not you.